# A fact about integration of $H^{1}(\mathbb R^{d})$ functions

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

For any $v \in  H^{1}(\mathbb R^{d})$ how to show that $\int_{\mathbb R^{d}} f(v).\nabla v dx = 0$ ; where $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^{d}$ is a Lipschitz continuous function such that $f(0) = 0$ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is misleading in that if you expand the scalar product, then the integral over each term is zero, so it is really a statement about scalar functions I would argue.

To prove the scalar valued version, try for $f$ (now a scalar valued function) the identity and then generalize. Ask if you have problems in executing this plan, but please add more info about your efforts than in the original question.

Comment: okay... let me try! Thank you for the idea.

Comment: Okay, my plan is to use the density of $\mathbb D(\Omega)$ in $H^{1}(\Omega)$ and firstly to show $\int_{\mathbb R^{d}}f_{i}(u).\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{i}}dx = 0 ; \forall i$  - where $u \in \mathbb D(\Omega)$. But here, I am facing problem since: $f$ is only Lipschitz Continuous, I cannot exchange the derivative. Help me if I am wrong.

Comment: again suppose $f$ is differentiable, then we can throw the derivative on $f$ & since it is Lipschitz, the derivative is bounded by some constant times the norm of $u$ but ; is it of any help??

Comment: you don't need to exchange the derivative. write it as integral over a derivative. for example, when $f$ is the identity, then you have $u \partial_i u=\partial_i (u^2)$.

Comment: for general $f$ you need to use the antiderivative of $f$. the lipschitzianity and the condition on the value at zero only ensure that things are integrable and the density argument works out.